# Обязательно ли двоеточие после слов "в следующем предложении"?

Tags: пунктуация

Типичный вопрос, задаваемый здесь:

**Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении? <*Предложение*>**

Мы обычно само предложение не берем в кавычки, а выделяем шрифтом. Я поставил двоеточие после слов "в следующем предложении", меня поправили. Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Неправильно поправили. Или - вполне правильно, если - случайно! - знак вопроса проскочил после слова "предложении".

> Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении?
>   <Предложение>

Совсем правильно будет так:

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

"Якось у зимову холодную пору из лису я вийшов; мороз так и гриз, дивлюсь - пидимаэться тихо пид гору конячка, на санях вивозячи хмиз"?

Кавычки нужны, потому что без них, играючи одним шрифтом, куда мы присобачим вопросительный знак вопросительного предложения?

Или так.

> Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении?

*Якось у зимову холодную пору из лису я вийшов; мороз так и гриз, дивлюсь - пидимаэться тихо пид гору конячка, на санях вивозячи хмиз.*

Иных вариантов не наблюдается.

Comment: Да и так "совсем правильно"! Ведь слова "в следующем предложении" получше всяких двоеточий позволяют это предложение найти.

Answer (score 2):

1) Здесь проблема в том, что **предложение вопросительное**. Когда нет вопроса, то ставят двоеточие.

Пример

Это же предложение в обратном порядке будет выглядеть следующим образом:

*Тёмная ночь, светлая вода и совершенно ясная погода - три условия, которые нужны для охоты с острогою.*

2) А поставить двоеточие в вопросительном предложении вроде бы нелогично, так как **вопросительная интонация не сочетается с пояснительной** (после слова *следующий*).  Вот пример, в котором автор не знает, что делать с вопросительным знаком.

Добрый вечер. Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: 
Покрытый кровавыми ранами (,) искалеченный зверь бежал без оглядки. ? Спасибо.

Скорее всего, **от двоеточия придется отказаться в пользу вопросительного знака.** Но это моё личное предположение. **И еще я могу предположить, что кавычки не нужны.** Почему? **Потому что мы  выделяем предложение позиционно (с новой строки).** Или уж курсивом выделять, да и то необязательно. И тогда у нас получается:

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Покрытый кровавыми ранами (,) искалеченный зверь бежал без оглядки.

3) У Розенталя: **Когда ставится точка, а не двоеточие.** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87#pp87

**Точка** ставится в конце предложения, вводящего в дальнейшее развернутое изложение: Вот этот рассказ. (Пауст.) [дальше следует рассказ]; Представьте себе **следующее**, [дальше — подробное повествование]; Новый станок имеет такое устройство. [дальше — пространное описание].

Answer (score 1):

Вот два первых попавшихся примера в Google.

1. Из [учебного пособия](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=nJIODAAAQBAJ&pg=PT22&lpg=PT22&dq=%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=x8_3A0u14C&sig=C9ccNlTDHURxuvUbi74CV0gvjRU&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj01_ySlcvZAhWFKlAKHT-yD8oQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0&f=false) для студентов-журналистов "Стилистика и литературное редактирование":

> Укажите, какая ошибка допущена в следующем предложении:
>
> Наставник от  всей души отругал меня за поломку фрезы?

2. Из сборника заданий ОГЭ-2018 для 9-го класса:

> В каком значении употреблено слово лицедейство в следующем
>   предложении?
>
> Театр — это Жизнь, это дивное лицедейство, горькая услада, сладчайшая
>   боль...

Хм.. Мне школьный вариант нравится больше.

Comment: Так в первом варианте задание не является вопросительным предложением, тогда можно двоеточие ставить. А во втором варианте оно как раз вопросительное, и вместо двоеточия стоит вопросительный знак. Кстати, ни кавычек, ни курсива нет.

Comment: @Jasmin Вы не поверите, но автор пособия считает в первом задании предложение вопросительным (знак вопроса в конце относится к заданию, а не к "следующему предложению"). Я сейчас добавлю ссылку в ответ, в комментарий она не помещается.